# MapReduce function with two different results

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

For the follow document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("511b7d1b3daee1b1446ecdfe"),
    "l_linenumber" : 1,
    "l_quantity" : 17,
    "l_extendedprice" : 21168.23,
    "l_discount" : 0.04,
    "l_tax" : 0.02,
    "l_returnflag" : "N",
    "l_linestatus" : "O",
    "l_shipdate" : ISODate("1996-03-13T03:00:00Z"),
    "l_commitdate" : ISODate("1996-02-12T03:00:00Z"),
    "l_receiptdate" : ISODate("1996-03-22T03:00:00Z"),
    "l_shipinstruct" : "DELIVER IN PERSON",
    "l_shipmode" : "TRUCK",
    "l_comment" : "blithely regular ideas caj",
}
```

I've tried two similar map reduce functions:
First

```
db.runCommand({
    mapreduce: "lineitem",
    query: {
        l_shipdate: {'$gte': new Date("Jan 01, 1994")},
        l_shipdate: {'$lt': new Date("Jan 01, 1995")},
        l_discount: {'$gte':0.05},
        l_discount: {'$lte':0.07},
        l_quantity: {'$lt':24}
    },
    map : function Map() {
            var revenue = this.l_extendedprice * this.l_discount;
            emit("REVENUE", revenue);
        },
    reduce : function(key, values) {
                return Array.sum(values);
            },
    out: 'query006'
});
```

Second

```
db.runCommand({
    mapreduce: "lineitem",
    map : function Map() {
            var dataInicial = new Date("Jan 1, 1994");
            var dataFinal = new Date("Jan 1, 1995");

            if( this.l_discount>=0.05 && this.l_discount<=0.07 && this.l_quantity<24 && this.l_shipdate>=dataInicial && this.l_shipdate<dataFinal) {
                var produto = this.l_extendedprice * this.l_discount;
                emit("revenue", produto);
            }
        },
    reduce : function(key, values) {
                return Array.sum(values);
            },
    out: 'query006'
```

### });

For me both functions are equals, and maybe return the same result. But the only the second return the correct answer.

These functions are my attempt to translate a SQL query presence in TPC-H benchmark. The query is shown here:

```
select
    sum(l_extendedprice*l_discount) as revenue
from 
    lineitem
where 
    l_shipdate >= date '1994-01-01'
    and l_shipdate < date '1994-01-01' + interval '1' year
    and l_discount between 0.06 - 0.01 and 0.06 + 0.01
    and l_quantity < 24;
```

Why when I use the query statement in the first function, the result is bigger than the correct answer? Are the functions the same indeed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your query violates the following paragraph from [$and operator documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/and/#_S_and):

> MongoDB provides an implicit AND operation when specifying a comma separated list of expressions. For example, you may write the above query as:
>
> `db.inventory.find( { price: 1.99, qty: { $lt: 20 } , sale: true } )`
>
> If, however, a query requires an AND operation on the same field such as `{ price: { $ne: 1.99 } } AND { price: { $exists: true } }`, then either use the `$and` operator for the two separate expressions or combine the operator expressions for the field `{ price: { $ne: 1.99, $exists: true } }`.

If we follow the advice of the documentation, the following query should do the trick:

```
query: {
    l_shipdate: {'$gte': new Date("Jan 01, 1994"), '$lt': new Date("Jan 01, 1995")},
    l_discount: {'$gte':0.05, '$lte':0.07},
    l_quantity: {'$lt':24}
},
```